# Lift \/[A, B] into EitherT[Future, A, B]

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

How to lift `\/[Error, Int]` into `EitherT[Future, Error, Int]` using `point/liftM` syntax such that lifting is on the right-hand side?

I have the following scenario

```
for {
  r1 <- f1: EitherT[Future, Error, Int]
  r2 <- v: \/[Error, Int]
  r3 <- f2: EitherT[Future, Error, Int]
} yield r3
```

I can make `v` fit by applying [`EitherT.fromDisjunction[Future]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300105/5205022) like so

```
for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- EitherT.fromDisjunction[Future](v)
  r3 <- f2
} yield r3
```

or simply

```
for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- EitherT(Future(v))
  r3 <- f2
} yield r3
```

however I am trying to move the lifting magic to the right-hand-side of `v` like so

```
for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- v.point[Future].liftM[EitherT] // something approximately like this
  r3 <- f2
} yield r3
```

I tried

```
type Result[F[_], A] = EitherT[F, Error, A]
v.point[Future].liftM[Result]
```

and

```
v.point[({ type L[x] = EitherT[Future, Error, x] })#L]
```

suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21993273/5205022) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890099/how-do-i-define-a-function-for-a-monad-stack-of-state-disjunction-and-list), however this types to

```
EitherT[Future, Error, Error \/ Int]
```

whilst I require

```
EitherT[Future, Error, Int]
```

Moving lifting to the right-hand-side is just for aesthetics, as `EitherT.fromDisjunction[Future]` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just

```
r2 <- v.eitherT[Future, Error, Int]
```

with

```
import scalaz.{EitherT, \/}
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._
import scalaz.syntax.eithert._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.language.higherKinds
```

Comment: Ah I was pulling in scalaz 7.2.7 as a transitive dependency which is few years old. This works with 2.7.27, however it seems it will be removed by [remove the EitherT syntax #1656](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/1656)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that exists in scalaz. There is no `toEitherT[F]` on disjunction. However it is trivial to add new syntax:

```
  implicit class EitherLiftSyntax[A, B](val self: A \/ B) extends AnyVal {
    def liftT[M[_]]: EitherT[M, A, B] = EitherT.fromDisjunction[M](self)
  }
```

As long as you have that in scope, you can say `v.liftT[Future]`